# Read table from text file

Tags: matlab, datetime-format

I'm trying to import data from a text file into the workspace by using the `readtable` function.

The text file structure is pretty simple, being composed by 4 columns of types *date*, *time*, *integer* and *float* respectively as shown in the following minimal example:

> 2013-07-07 05:15:19 8 213.0
>
> 2013-07-07 05:15:19 11 109.0
>
> 2013-07-07 05:15:20 14 33.5
>
> 2013-07-07 05:15:24 56 182.0

When I try to load the data like this:

```
data = readtable(filename,...
                'Format','%{yyyy-MM-dd}D %{HH:mm:ss}D %d %f %*[^\n]',...
                'ReadVariableNames',false);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using textscan
Badly formed format string.

Error in table/readTextFile (line 160)
raw = textscan(fid,format,'delimiter',delimiter,'whitespace',whiteSpace, ...

Error in table.readFromFile (line 41)
    t = table.readTextFile(filename,otherArgs);

Error in readtable (line 114)
t = table.readFromFile(filename,varargin);
```

If I try this instead:

```
data = readtable(filename,...
                'Format','%{yyyy-MM-dd}D%{HH:mm:ss}D%d%f%*[^\n]',...
                'Delimiter',' ',...
                'ReadVariableNames',false);
```

I get the exactly same error.

I've checked the [Mathwork's online documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html), but I was unable to find the solution to my problem.

EDIT: Actually, the desired table format would be to have a *datetime* column replacing the *date* and *time* columns. What I'm doing is joining *date* and *time* manually after reading the table. If you know a way to import the table merging those 2 variables straight away, that would be great.

Comment: Are you using R2014b+? I'm not sure if the `'%{yyyy-MM-dd}D'` style formatspec exists in earlier versions. If you're not using the most recent version, make sure that you're reading the documentation that came with your install, not the online documentation (though there is [archived documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html)).

Comment: @horchler Well spotted! That seems to be the issue here, since I'm running Matlab R2013b which apparently doesn't recognize `%{fmt}D` formatspec.

Answer (score 1):

Initially if you will do this with your data format:

```
data = readtable('data.txt','Delimiter',' ','ReadVariableNames',false)
```

You will get Nx4 data array so that you can manipulate it as much as you like.

You can read on how to manipulate with the data imported as table [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html)

Comment: That may work, but it looks like it just imports everything as strings, since all values aren't numeric.

Comment: seems like that, but data is accessible via curly brackets and might be not the most efficient way to recast the data. I have added link

Comment: @madbitloman I'm aware of that. In fact that's kind of what I'm doing right now.. I was just wondering if there was any better way to import the data to the desired format in one step instead of post-processing it.